# What is the most standard way of zipping two collections into a hash?

Tags: ruby

Two collections of equal size, such as

```
u = :a, :b, :c
v = 1, 2, 3
```

can be easily zipped:

```
u.map.with_index { |e, i| [e, v[i] ] }
```

But why bother when there is `#zip` method:

```
u.zip v
```

Similarly, they can be easily zipped into a hash:

```
Hash[ u.zip v ]
```

My question is, does Ruby core, stdlib or any of the famous gems have a standard method to perform this frequent operation? I envision something like:

```
u.hashzip v #=> { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
u.hashzip &:to_s #=> { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" }
```

Comment: Let's see... What is that gem :)) But the last one I don't understand `u.hashzip &:to_s #=> { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" }` ?

Comment: @Priti: I do not know what is the most frequently used gem that implements this, and that's the subject of my question. But I am sure that dozens of people have written libraries with this particular function. By `u.hashzip &:to_s #=> { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" }` I mean applying the block to each element, that should be obvious.

Comment: `Hash[u.zip(v)]` is simple enough, isn't it?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky see here - http://rubydoc.info/gems/hash-utils/2.1.2/frames

Comment: And in addition to @sawa answer, if you want to pass a block to either values or keys, call them respectively with map and voila.

Comment: The method @Priti means is `Hash.combine(u,v)`

Comment: @padde Yes,, you are right! :)

Comment: +1 on `Hash[u.zip(v)]`.

Comment: @padde: Thanks for the clarification. But, are you guys really using that library, or just recommend it to me because the authori is also from Czech Republic like me? Because [looking at the download statistics](https://rubygems.org/gems/hash-utils), the author had 164 downloads for the current version, and he released it 1 month ago... (For comparison, [active_support had 81,000 downloads](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) for the last 10 days... Priti: Please make it an answer, but isn't there some more frequently used gem for this?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I will,Now I am in Office :)) No access to Ruby :(

Comment: @sawa: Not when you are building DSLs. It then matters whether the user has to type `Hash[ simulation.places.zip( simulation.places.map &:marking ) ]` or `simulation.places.hashzip &:marking`. There is always a question of how much functionality you have to provide in the DSL, and how much you leave to the plain Ruby.

Comment: @Dogbert: Exactly, up to the point that I said in the OP and that Priti already answered with `hash-utils`. I'm still waiting if someone knows more frequently used gem.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky, I don't think `Hash.combine` supports arguments like `&:to_s`...?

Comment: @Dogbert There are methods at the bottom of that libaray to support that *Hash.combine supports arguments like &:to_s*. I can't test now. But some method smells like that. I am not sure about that also.

Comment: This is offtopic for stack overflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hash[u.zip(v)]` is the most concise and common idiom for converting two equal-size arrays into a hash that I've seen. Comparing it to `Hash.combine`:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'pp'

# From:
#     http://rubydoc.info/gems/hash-utils/2.1.2/Hash#combine-class_method
class Hash
  def self.combine(keys, values)
    result = {}
    keys.each_index do |i|
      result[keys[i]] = values[i]
    end

    return result
  end
end

def zip_method(a, b)
  Hash[a.zip(b)]
end

ALPHA = ('a' .. 'z').to_a * 25
NUMERIC = (0 .. 25).to_a * 25
N = 10_000

puts "N = #{ N }"
puts "Ruby version = " + `ruby -v`

pp Hash.combine(%w[a b c], [1, 2, 3])
pp Hash[%w[a b c].zip([1, 2, 3])]
pp zip_method(%w[a b c], [1, 2, 3])

Benchmark.bm(10) do |x|
  x.report('zip') { N.times { Hash[ALPHA.zip(NUMERIC)] }}
  x.report('zip_method') { N.times { zip_method(ALPHA, NUMERIC) }}
  x.report('combine') { N.times { Hash.combine(ALPHA, NUMERIC) }}
end
```

With these results:

```
N = 10000
Ruby version = ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
                 user     system      total        real
zip          1.990000   0.010000   2.000000 (  1.993747)
zip_method   1.980000   0.000000   1.980000 (  1.990298)
combine      2.130000   0.000000   2.130000 (  2.133492)
```

I added `zip_method` to see what difference calling the method would make. Oddly enough, it doesn't make any. I'm probably missing something.

This sort of question has been around for a while: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/125944

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that answering own questions is mildly encouraged here, I have now come to the point where made the "hashzip" method a part of my `y_support` gem, overloading `>>` operator:

```
require 'y_support/core_ext/array'

x = :a, :b, :c
y = 1, 2, 3

x >> y
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```